# How do I delete gamer profile on xbox 360

Tags: xbox-360

I have a couple of gamer profiles that aren't used anymore but I can't find out how to delete them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to your settings and find system -> storage
then click on the drive you use to save (Most likely your hard drive)
Then go to profiles, find the one you want to delete there, click on it and select delete

so in short:
settings -> storage -> hard drive -> profiles -> 'profileThatNeedsDeleting'

NOTE: You'll have to decide between **Delete Profile Only** and **Delete Profile and Items** 
**Delete Profile Only** = delete the profile but keep the saved games and achievements
**Delete Profile and Items** = delete the profile and all the games and achievements that go along with it

Comment: This is the official guide microsoft provides if you still have trouble -> http://support.xbox.com/en-US/my-account/manage-gamertag-and-profile/delete-xbox-live-profile-from-xbox-360-console